# Error: No named parameter with the name 'readOnly'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

```
FormBuilder(
    key: _fbKey,
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
    readOnly: false
)
```

This was working great 2 months ago. Now, I want to change something on my app and this error occurs. Any thought's? I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Also now I get the error:
No named parameter with the name 'attribute'

```
FormBuilderTextField(
     attribute: "emailFromUser",
     ....
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the change log in flutter_form_field package you will see the following points:

Attribute readOnly replaced by enabled - this was done to match Flutter's FormField naming convention

Renamed attribute option in all fields to name

Here is the link
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder/changelog

You should also look into semantic versioning to understand how package versions change. And look into pubspec.lock